# Error 'No such file or directory' while sending files from s3 bucket using airflow 'EmailOperator'

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I need to send csv files present in aws s3 bucket using airflow EmailOperator.

Hi,

I am facing 'No such file or directory' error when I am trying to send 2 csv files present in s3 bucket to a recipient using Airflow EmailOperator.

Am I doing right, sending files from s3 bucket ? Or Is it possible ?

Also, I do not want any local storage to be used in this regards, the reason being, my MWAA has minimal temp storage and file may not be available in the temp for the worker node to pick it if worker node gets changed in the process.

Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried to do this, but my understanding of how the EmailOperator works is that the files need to be on the local filesystem. If you have control over where your tasks are executed, its possible you could create a task that downloads those files in one task, and then email them in a second. However, if you are using something like MWAA this is not going to work as workers that execute tasks are "stateless" in so far as you cannot guarantee that two tasks will execute on the same underlying compute host.

One alternative might be to have a function that generates a signed S3 URL and then links to the S3 attachments that way.